# how to add two adapters in a single listview

Tags: android, listview

> I am try to display two textviews in single list. But i can not display two adapters at a time. And i try to change values of textview at runtime. It get update value from a dialog box. It's working but not display two adapters at a time.My code is

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
ArrayList<String> arrayList,a1;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter,a2;
RatingBar r1,r2,r3,r4,r5;
TextView t;
Float beh,b,f;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    String[] items={"Apple","Banana","Coconut","Grape","Peach","Pear"};
    String[] i={"0","0","0","0","0","0"};
    a1=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(i));
    arrayList=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
    arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.layout, R.id.textView,arrayList);
    a2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.layout, R.id.textView2,a1);
    listView.setAdapter(a2);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Show input box
            showInputBox(a1.get(position),position);
        }
     });

     }
     public void showInputBox(String oldItem, final int index){
     final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("School details");
    r1 = (RatingBar)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    r2 = (RatingBar)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar2);

    Button s=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
    s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            f = (beh + b) / 2;
            a1.set(index, f.toString());
            a2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();

    r1.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {

            beh = rating;
            //String beh = Float.toString(rating);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), beh.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
       });
       r2.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new     RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {

             b = rating;
            //String b = Float.toString(rating);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), b.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
     });
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By using custom adapter i can use two textView are handled at runtime in listView. I solved this problem with this code

```
       private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener() {
        return new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(student_login.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_dialog);
            int layout=R.layout.item_listview;



            final School staf = (School) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            final String stname = staf.getName().toString();
            String scname = staf.getSchool();
            final String poid=staf.getObjid();
            final String pb = staf.getBehaviour();
            final String pk = staf.getKnowledge();
            final String pp= staf.getPresentation();
            final String pe=staf.getExplanation();
            final String ppu = staf.getPunctuality();
            final String c = staf.getCoun();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), poid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            dialog.setTitle(scname + "-" + stname);

            dialog.show();

            r1 = (RatingBar)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
            r2 = (RatingBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar2);
            r3 = (RatingBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar3);
            r4 = (RatingBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar4);
            r5 = (RatingBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar5);
            Button sav= (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);

            sav.setTag(position);



            r1.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new              RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {

                    beh = rating;

                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), beh, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
            r2.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {

                    k=rating;

                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), k, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });


            sav .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String position =v.getTag().toString();
                    int po=Integer.parseInt(position);
                    f=(beh+k+p+e+pu)/5;
                    String sf=String.valueOf(f);

                    View view = listView.getChildAt(po);
                    TextView someText = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView6));
                    someText.setText(f.toString());

                    String tsf=staf.getCrate();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tsf, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });


        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer is.. you can't

you'll either need two seperate list vies. 
Or inside your adapter, operate on two seperate lists to produce the result you want.

Can't help much more without knowing more about what you want to achieve.

Edit:
To add more textviews etc to each row, you'll need a custom adapter.
Here's a good tutorial - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown

Comment: i am try to give rating for the presented list item from the dialog box and save the rating into another textview in the listview. The dialog box contain two rating bars and a button.

Comment: Thank you for your help.